# Apache Archiva Failure/Corruption: ERROR org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemManager [] - failed to retrieve item state of item

Tags: maven, archiva

I am using `Apache` `Archiva` for a repo that my `Maven` build hits. I have had no issues with it for the past 3 months until today; I do builds regularly and it has been stable with no issues until now. I am seeing the following error in my logs:

```
021-01-22 23:00:00,951 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.BundleFsPersistenceManager [] - failed to read bundle: e105d1e9-c3aa-45e1-bdb5-ca2be2298eb2: java.io.EOFException
2021-01-22 23:00:00,951 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemManager [] - failed to retrieve item state of item e105d1e9-c3aa-45e1-bdb5-ca2be2298eb2
org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.ItemStateException: failed to read bundle: e105d1e9-c3aa-45e1-bdb5-ca2be2298eb2: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.BundleFsPersistenceManager.loadBundle(BundleFsPersistenceManager.java:249) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.getBundleCacheMiss(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:769) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.getBundle(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:752) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.load(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:490) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.loadItemState(SharedItemStateManager.java:1873) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.getNonVirtualItemState(SharedItemStateManager.java:1793) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.getItemState(SharedItemStateManager.java:270) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.LocalItemStateManager.getNodeState(LocalItemStateManager.java:110) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.LocalItemStateManager.getItemState(LocalItemStateManager.java:175) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.XAItemStateManager.getItemState(XAItemStateManager.java:260) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SessionItemStateManager.getItemState(SessionItemStateManager.java:161) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemManager.getItemData(ItemManager.java:382) [jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemManager.getNode(ItemManager.java:669) [jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemManager.getNode(ItemManager.java:647) [jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.LazyItemIterator.prefetchNext(LazyItemIterator.java:120) [jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.LazyItemIterator.next(LazyItemIterator.java:257) [jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.archiva.metadata.repository.jcr.JcrMetadataRepository.recurse(JcrMetadataRepository.java:465) [metadata-store-jcr-2.2.4.jar:?]
        at org.apache.archiva.metadata.repository.jcr.JcrMetadataRepository.recurse(JcrMetadataRepository.java:470) [metadata-store-jcr-2.2.4.jar:?]
        at org.apache.archiva.metadata.repository.jcr.JcrMetadataRepository.recurse(JcrMetadataRepository.java:470) [metadata-store-jcr-2.2.4.jar:?]
        at org.apache.archiva.metadata.repository.jcr.JcrMetadataRepository.getMetadataFacets(JcrMetadataRepository.java:449) [metadata-store-jcr-2.2.4.jar:?]
        at org.apache.archiva.metadata.repository.stats.DefaultRepositoryStatisticsManager.getLastStatistics(DefaultRepositoryStatisticsManager.java:76) [repository-statistics-2.2.4.jar:?]
        at org.apache.archiva.scheduler.repository.ArchivaRepositoryScanningTaskExecutor.executeTask(ArchivaRepositoryScanningTaskExecutor.java:138) [archiva-scheduler-repository-2.2.4.jar:?]
        at org.apache.archiva.scheduler.repository.ArchivaRepositoryScanningTaskExecutor.executeTask(ArchivaRepositoryScanningTaskExecutor.java:54) [archiva-scheduler-repository-2.2.4.jar:?]
        at org.apache.archiva.redback.components.taskqueue.execution.ThreadedTaskQueueExecutor$ExecutorRunnable$1.run(ThreadedTaskQueueExecutor.java:117) [spring-taskqueue-2.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473) [?:1.7.0_272]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [?:1.7.0_272]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152) [?:1.7.0_272]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622) [?:1.7.0_272]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.7.0_272]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290) ~[?:1.7.0_272]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.util.BundleReader.<init>(BundleReader.java:132) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.util.BundleBinding.readBundle(BundleBinding.java:152) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.BundleFsPersistenceManager.loadBundle(BundleFsPersistenceManager.java:242) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        ... 28 more
```

A cursory review of this issue with `Archiva` is not promising, rather similar questions as my own. I am using Archiva 2.2.4. The application is runhning on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. There have been no issues on this server to my knowledge such as HDD space running out. Has anyone else seen this or can anyone provide any tips on dealing with this? I am loath to say it but I feel like I may need to simply reinstall this application.

Comment: Hi Olaf, were you able to resolve the problem?
Having the exact same issue here, and got no clue how to resolve it other than setting up a fresh installation (which I'd like to avoid).
So if you have any clues, I'd be forever grateful...